# Ask user input for an array position? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

I searched the forum and all answers are python or C+ related, this is for ruby.

I'm trying to figure out how to make the below program prompt the user for an item in the array by typing a number 1-4 (so the position wouldn't start from 0 in the users eyes).
It's probably a simple fix, but I am new to this.. I appreciate any time and help.

```
array = []

puts "please add to the array 4 times"

4.times do
array << gets.chomp

end

puts "#{array}"
puts "Select a position in the array by typing a singular number from 1-4"
```

Comment: forgot to add.. the program would pull that 1-4 position out of the array. So depending on what was inputted into the array, that is what would come out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
array = []
puts "please add to the array 4 times"

4.times do
  array << gets.chomp
end

puts "#{array}"

loop do
  puts "Select a position in the array by typing a singular number from 1-4"
  ans = gets.chomp.to_i
  if ans > 0 && ans <= array.length 
    puts "The element at position #{ans} is " + array[ans-1]
    break
  else
    puts "You have to pick a number between 1 & 4, try again."
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks sagarpandya! much easier/basic to understand :)

Answer (score -1):

You can get the index by combining `gets.chomp` (reads a line of user input and removes the trailing newline character) and `to_i` (convert to integer).

Combine this with the ability to access an array's element at a specific index using the `array[index_integer]` method.

To piece it together:

```
array = ["first_item", "second_item", "third_item"]
puts "enter the array index: "
index = gets.chomp.to_i
adjusted_index = index - 1
value_at_index = array[adjusted_index]
puts "The element at that index is #{value_at_index}"
```

However be forewarned that the index will 'loop around' to -1 if a value of 0 is given.

For example, if the user enters 0, then `adjusted_index` will be -1 and the last element of the array will be displayed.

Comment: thanks max, how would you piece this into the above code?

Comment: i'm having a hard time linking it to the 4.times loop with the objects i'm using